# is there quick way to export an array to Excel file using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have arrays of points that contain series data (x & y). Is there a quick way to output these arrays into an excel file?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Output the data to a file, separating the array elements with commas.  Then save the file as name.csv

Use FileWriter to output the file.

Answer (score 8):

One of this nice things about range object is that you can assign a two dimensional array to directly to the value property. It *is* important that the range be the same number of cells as the array has elements.

```
        //using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
        String[,] myArr = new string[10, 10];
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                myArr[x, y] = "Test " + y.ToString() + x.ToString();
            }
        }
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range rng = ws.Cells.get_Resize(myArr.GetLength(0), myArr.GetLength(1));
        rng.Value2 = myArr;
```

Comment: +1. This is the way I would go. But I would make use of the Range.get_Resize() method in order to size your range to the correct dimensions, instead of hardcoding it with strings. But you've got my vote. :-)

Comment: With Excel 2016, had to use Excel.Range rng = ws.Cells.Resize(myArr.GetLength(0), myArr.GetLength(1));

Answer (score 4):

If CSV is not satisfactory, you can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  An example is at [How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I would use a third-party xsl export component. This would save you the hassle of excel automation, and you wouldn't have to bundle the excel interop assemblies with your application.

[MyXls](https://sourceforge.net/projects/myxls/) is a simple open-source component that does excel exports. It should cover your needs just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using Ado.net. My code below assumes that there's an excel spreadsheet called Book1.xls in a folder C:\Stuff\ and that the spread sheet has the headers ID, Name, Site already present in a sheet called Sheet1.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                    Data Source=C:\Stuff\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=
                    ""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {

            using (OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] (ID, Name, Site) VALUES(1, ""Phil"", ""StackOverflow.com"")";
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```